# Windows Phone 8: CSS orientation not recognized

Tags: javascript, css, orientation, media-queries, windows-phone-8

I am attempting to pick up orientation on all mobile devices in css and trigger some css on the orientation change.

This is a simple test of the code:

```
    <div class="orientation">
        <span class="landscape">Landscape</span>
        <span class="portrait">Portrait</span>
    </div>
```

and the CSS is:

```
     .portrait, .landscape {
         position: absolute;
         top: 0px;
         left: 0px;
     }

    .portrait {display: block;}
    .landscape {display: none;}

    @media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
        .portrait {display: none;}
        .landscape {display: block;}
    }
```

Now in all webkit browsers (android, ios)  and even desktop it works fine (bar a couple of devices) but in the new windows phone 8 devices it doesn't pick up the change. (Nokia lumia 920)

I've also had a look at some javascript resources (I am no javascript wiz though) namely:

- http://www.developria.com/2010/08/detecting-screen-orientation-i.html
- http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change

But from what i can tell, that still doesn't work for windows phone 8 devices?

Is there a specific MS css code I need to use or is there another way to do it? it would be great if there was a cross browser / cross mobile device capable piece of javascript that can pick up the change and just add a class to the body tag on the change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: As a test, you could add a piece of javascript and just do `alert(window.orientation);` to see if there's any difference between landscape and orientation. But the fact that it ignores the media queries is mighty annoying.

Comment: It most definitely is. I did find some other info regarding the media queries and it seems window 8 supports this:
'@media (-ms-view-state: fullscreen-landscape)'
'@media (-ms-view-state: filled)'
'@media (-ms-view-state: snapped)'
'@media (-ms-view-state: fullscreen-portrait)'

Not sure if its just for metro app built using JS and CSS or if its also for normal sites.
Also not sure if windows Phone 8 supports this. still testing now.

Comment: OK, so apparently those "ms-view-state" media queries I mentioned earlier are only for the windows 8 apps it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@media all and (orientation:landscape)` is definitely the right direction you should take. There's a live demo of that in the build2012 talk on WP8 and HTML. See time stamp 35:30~ for orientation changes on WP8 IE10 @ http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/2-015

Comment: Thanks @justinAngel. I'll have a look at it as soon as I have the actual phone device in my hand to test. The one thing I notice from your code to mine is that you are targeting "All" for the media query, whereas I am targeting only "screen". Would the windows phone really not pick up the media query using "screen"?? strange. I'll let you know what I find and come back to answer this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JustinAngel. I can confirm that this definitely does NOT work on the Nokia lumia 920 (with IE10 supposedly). I have set up a quick test page here http://goo.gl/OxPmQ. If someone other than myself could test this with a new windows phone 8 device and let me know if they find it working or not. (must be windows phone 8 with IE10 - the older windows phone 8 with IE9 does work perfectly - namely HTC HD7 with OS upgraded)

Comment: I am marking this as correct as the error I posted seems to be a development server issue for some reason. I am building the project in visual studio, publishing to my local machine in IIS and then accessing the site using mobile devices for testing. All the mobile devices pick up the media query, but the windows phone doesn't. That's why I didn't think it was a localised issue.    When we publish the site to a proper live testing server the media query is fine on all devices. Odd I know, but another issue for another time.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [blog entry](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/15/adapting-your-webkit-optimized-site-for-internet-explorer-10.aspx#step2), when you view a web page locally, IE defaults into backwards compatible mode for intranet sites. This is probably what's causing it not to work as intended. You can fix it by adding the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Thanks Milo, ill give this a try next time im working on it! Good to know

Comment: thanks, it does fixed my bugs on nokia lumia 1020 mail client!!

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a bit of an old question, I had this same issue with orientation not being recognized by IE11 on a Surface Pro 2 tablet.  It came down to whitespace.  I thought I'd share the solution in case someone else has the same issue.

Doesn’t work:

`@media all and (orientation : portrait) {`

Works:

`@media all and (orientation:portrait) {`